# endless loop of messagebox

Tags: c#

This set of codes apparently, is to retrieve the data from the server (from a certain period of days) and to display them in a notepad. Im not sure why, it keeps popping out message box "char", "money" and "nvarchar". Pardon me if its a silly question

```
  SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 0 )) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpTo.Text+"', 0))", objConn);

        SqlDataReader objReader;
        objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Sales-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        int count = 0;
        while (objReader.Read())
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
                {
                    string s;
                    s = objReader.GetDataTypeName(i);
                    MessageBox.Show(s);
                    if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "char")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "datetime")

                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetSqlMoney(i).ToString());
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "nvarchar")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }
                }
                if (i < 4)
                {
                    sw.Write("\t");
                }

            }
            count = count + 1;
            sw.WriteLine();

        }
        sw.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        objReader.Close();
        objConn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(count + " records exported successfully.");
        this.Close();
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dtpTo_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not wish to handle the `Money` type of column?

Comment: My good sir!! can i buy u a drink! u are awesome!!

Comment: @Aphelion sir, my bad, its supposed to be money. and its my fault for that bad code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `MessageBox` being shown inside the loop which is why you're seeing multiple `MessageBox`es with the data types. If you really don't want to see them, just remove the following line:

```
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your datasource contains a column of the type `Money`. Note that you do not handle the money type.
That is why one of the messageBoxes contains the 'Money' text.